# How to solve integer divisions that produces integer result using Z3?

Tags: z3, smt

Say I have a z3 expression:

```
c = z3.Int("x")
Expr = (-c) / 2
```

Is it possible to use Z3 to find any C so that the expression evaluates to an integer?

For example, if c==1, this whole equation should evaluates to -0.5 and thus not an integer.

I've tried to model the problem using reminder==0 approach

```
>>> from z3 import *
>>> c = Int("c")
>>> s = Solver()
>>> s.add(((-c) %2)==0)
>>> s.check()
sat
```

Which is obviously incorrect. Changing to `c = Real("c")` gives an exception:

```
>>> c = Real("c")
>>> s = Solver()
>>> s.add(((-c) %2)==0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/z3/z3.py", line 2539, in __mod__
    _z3_assert(a.is_int(), "Z3 integer expression expected")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/z3/z3.py", line 112, in _z3_assert
    raise Z3Exception(msg)
z3.z3types.Z3Exception: Z3 integer expression expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%` over integers will be evaluated as integer remainder; so what you proposed actually works just fine:

```py
from z3 import *

c = Int("c")
s = Solver()
s.add(((-c) %2)==0)
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

This prints:

```
sat
[c = 2]
```

and indeed, the model says `c` can be the integer 2, and `-c%2` will be `0` as one would expect.

If you also add the assertion that `c` is `1`:

```py
from z3 import *

c = Int("c")
s = Solver()
s.add(((-c) %2)==0)
s.add(c == 1)
print(s.check())
```

then you get:

```
unsat
```

as expected. So, this all works just as required. Perhaps you're trying to ask something else?

Comment: Ah thanks, now I got it. I initially misunderstood the concepts as "If it says sat, then every possible val should sat" instead of "there must be a value that satisfies while other might not"